# Python Widget that can show both HTML & CSS

Tags: python, html, wxpython, tkinter

I have an idea to create a Parental Supervision Web Browser. The way it works is that I create a desktop application in python(preferably using wxPython or wxPythons webkit) thats just a widget that can display HTML & CSS.

HTTP requests for a website will go through a proxy on my server. So if someone wants to access the website "http://google.com":
- they type in that url in the python browser
- the request goes to my script on my server: http://mywebserver.com/cgi-bin/browserRequest.py?url=http://google.com
- The python script checks the url against a list of invalid urls; if it passes then the script downloads/accesses the webpage & sends back the HTML & where relevant external css or javascript files

**My Question: What python GUI libraries have simple easy to use widgets that display HTML AND can display CSS?**

I am finding that most HTML widgets cant display CSS especially in wxpython. Plus some widgets dont allow your html to have html or body tag elements. Do you know of the best widget either in wxpython or in any python based GUI that can show HTML & CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Webkit in PyQt (or PySide) and PyGTK

http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtWebKit/index.html

http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2008/03/creating-rich-internet-applications-on-linux-with-webkit.ars

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ee8eRwjbcFk

Comment: There's also a wxWebkit port to wxPython currently being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) instead of Python for this project.

XULRunner is a toolkit created by Mozilla and is used in Firefox and Thunderbird to create the GUI and such.

It is based on XUL (an XML-like language) and JavaScript with extensive support for DOM-interactions (like loading pages and tweaking CSS/HTML on-the-fly).

But if you *insist* on Python, PyQt4 has a pretty nice web widget that uses Webkit to render the HTML and CSS.